# React Native - How to round value of Animated component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to create text animation using `Animated API` but the value of animated has decimal, I want to rounded that value, is it possible?

I've tried using `Math.round()` but the output is `NaN`,

here's the code:

```
const AnimatedText = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(CustomText);


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.visited = new Animated.Value(0)
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    Animated.timing(this.visited,{
      toValue: 1,
      duration:1000,
    }).start();
  }

  render(){
    const visiting = this.visited.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [0, 20],
    });
    return(
      <AnimatedText style={{fontSize:40, color:'white', fontWeight:'900'}}>{visiting}</AnimatedText>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: probably do checking on the value first if it's a number and if it is you can pass it to `Math.round`, i.e. `typeof value === 'number' ? Math.round(value) : 0`

Comment: I've used `typeof` last time, and the result is `object`

Comment: then the return animated value is not a valid js number. Could you try to console log the animated value to check if the object has any number value property which can be rounded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `new Animated.Value` creates a custom react native object. If you want to get the value, you can either stop the animation and get the current value:

```
this.state.visited.stopAnimation(value => console.log(Math.round(value.value)))
```

Or add a listener to it and always get the most recent value while the animation is running:

```
componentWillMount(){
    this.state.visited.addListener(value => console.log(Math.round(value.value)))
    Animated.timing(this.visited,{
      toValue: 1,
      duration:1000,
    }).start();
}
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#responding-to-the-current-animation-value